# Token transfer failed - Reverted

Tags: tokens

i trying transfer tokens ERC20, but all my transactions failed - Reverted.

Example "0x4fe5b29d3fabaac6bc7b82574ab7f2a6d024134ca927fa9315e824c74c3d1364"

But i trying with "MetaMask" and transaction success

"0x4e9295875fa4488062fbbf8d0f14f5a5dbea2672cc8c248900c5d9610417c55f"

I think it is because price of gas and fee.

But i not choose these prices.

In my node i execute only

tcm.transferFrom(eth.accounts[0], '0x36A0e64b6c5a875f859E72eF4471c30d78ab4D1e', 1000000000000000000);

How i change price of gas and/or fee price?

Comment: where did you try to run the transferFrom function? I don't think this is not because of the gas price and fee. Because you can see the error something like "out of gas"  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x963d1ad0bec3f95517d427e8cb7cc262f421bc4ae14046f7bfdb695e548d2419

Comment: Error is Reverted. What is that?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the same network as in metamask?

Comment: @IngridCristaldo usually, when the require condition is not passed, then you will get revert error.